# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.gatewayrestaurant.model1

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

**Show data from Firebase in fragment**
**Getting this Error**
**I have No idea what the error is**
**any help would be appreciated**
Making a simple application where Firebase data is shown in the app.
** I have tried in a normal activity it worked.
but in the fragment, it's not working**

**Model1 class**

```
package com.example.gatewayrestaurant;

public class model1 {

    String image,name,price;

    public model1() {
    }

    public model1(String image, String name, String price) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

**Myadapter**

```
package com.example.gatewayrestaurant;

public class myadaptersoutindian extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model1,myadaptersoutindian.myviewholder> {


    public myadaptersoutindian(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model1> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull model1 model) {
        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.img);
        holder.menuTitle.setText(model.getName());
        holder.price.setText(model.getPrice());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.southindiancardview,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);

    }

    public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView img;
        TextView menuTitle,price;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
            menuTitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_title);
            price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ftab1 extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    RecyclerView recview;
    myadaptersoutindian adapter;

    public ftab1() {
    }


    public static ftab1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ftab1 fragment = new ftab1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftab1, container, false);

        recview=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recview);
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model1> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model1>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("southindian"), model1.class)
                        .build();

        adapter=new myadaptersoutindian(options);
        recview.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.gatewayrestaurant.model1
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:36)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:109)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:149)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
2021-01-28 10:42:28.545 3914-3914/com.example.gatewayrestaurant E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1099)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23750)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3712)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3164)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2225)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9126)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:999)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:732)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

***[image: I am New to android and connecting with firebase in fragment]***
Any other Method to show firebase data in fragment will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.gatewayrestaurant.model1

Because you are passing the following reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("southindian")
```

To the "setQuery()" method, meaning that each child under that reference will be rendered as an object of type "model1". This actually not possible because, under the "southindian" node, only three String object exists, hence that error. Bear in mind that in Java, there is not way you can convert an object of type String tp "model1", because there is no inheritance relationship between them.

I personally doubt, but if the "menu" child has the same properties as the "southindian" child, then you should pass to that method, the following reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
```

Without the call to .child("southindian"). Meaning that each child will be treated as an object of type "model1". If that's not the case, then remove the first "menu" child or try to create another schema in which in a single node, to store only objects of the same type.

Comment: menu child doesnt have the same properties as southindian class

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: As I told you, remove that child and add it to another place. Or create another structure in which you should add, only objects of type model1.

Comment: thank you sir , for teaching me . The Problem was with String Price in model1 class. As it was not String.Converted to long and it worked. Thank You